# How to replace my factory in my unit test without constructor dependency injection?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

Usnig **xUnit** and **Moq**.

**EDIT1:** This approach is going to be used in a library and I want to have parameterless constructor. I do not want my application project to know about dependencies of my library

**EDIT2:** I just read, that this is form of [property DI](https://jeremybytes.blogspot.com/2014/01/dependency-injection-property-injection.html). I think to stick to it, if noone have any better ideas.

I am using factory pattern in my solution. For testing purposes I want to replace my factory with its mock. Below will be simplified example. In my service class constructor I am creating instance of my factory:

```
public class ObjectService : IObjectService
    {
        public ObjectService()
        {
            Factory = new ObjectFactory();
        }

        public IObjectFactory Factory { get; set; }

        public IObjectModel GetObject(string firstName)
        {
            return Factory.GetObject(firstName);
        }
    }
```

So in unit tests I can replace instance of the factory with mock:

```
public class ObjectServiceTests
    {
        private readonly ObjectService _serv;
        private readonly Mock<IObjectFactory> _factoryMock;
        private readonly Mock<ISomeService> _someServMock;
        private readonly string _someFirstName = "SomeFirstName";

        public ObjectServiceTests()
        {
            _someServMock = new Mock<ISomeService>();
            _someServMock.SetupGet(s => s.SecondName).Returns("Cos");

            _factoryMock = new Mock<IObjectFactory>();
            _factoryMock.Setup(f => f.GetObject(_someFirstName))
                .Returns(new ObjectModel(_someFirstName, _someServMock.Object));

            _serv = new ObjectService();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void GetObject_Called_ReturnsObject()
        {
            _serv.Factory = _factoryMock.Object;

            IObjectModel newObj = _serv.GetObject(_someFirstName);

            Assert.Equal(_someFirstName + ", Cos", newObj.FullName);
        }
    }
```

I am wondering, is my approach with using `public IObjectFactory Factory { get; set; }` property correct? Because currently I have no any other idea how to do it. I will be happy for any suggestions how to replace my factory in tested method in other way.

Comment: I know this isn't Code Review, but what does this Service class actually do? What problem does it solve? Why can't its called depend on `IObjectFactory` instead?

Comment: This approach is going to be used in a class library, and I want to avoid constructor DI, otherwise IoC container will try to resolve its dependencies.

Comment: And what's the problem with that? It's a common pattern to add an extension method to your library that initializes the DI container of choice for that particular library. If you _don't_ what that, if you want to hardcode your injections, perhaps provide an internal constructor that's accessible by your unit tests

Comment: Actually I do not want my application project to know about dependencies of my library.

Comment: Then see the second part of my comment.

Comment: But if I will inject my library to the application project, as I understand, the application will see the internal constructor of the library. Or I am wrong? After your suggestion I am considering using `private` constructor...

Comment: @bakunet See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.8 for details on how your test project can see `internal` but other projects cannot.